# Qt DLL with GUI

Tags: qt, qt5, dll-injection

So basically I am trying to attach Qt dll that has a gui to a 3rd party non-Qt application.
When the dll is attached the window form should show.

I can not find any working example.
I need the simplest form of a working example if possible please.

Comment: What do you men with "attach"?

Comment: dll attach - inject - load.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I believe that good start point would be to create an application which loads external dll (empty) with linked Qt libraries. Then you can go on.